# Servers and clients implementing SFTP Protocol version 6

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, sftp

As is, SFTP protocol version 3, which is the most widely used version, especially in `OpenSSH` which implements it uniformly, does not provide folder size information, and this information can only uniformly be obtained by iterating through the files within said folder.

`OpenSSH` does provide the command, `df -h`, to get the size of the filesystem on which the folder is hosted, but unless one creates filesystems / logical volumes per folder, this information would not help, also this is a `proprietary` implementation of `OpenSSH`. Some clients, like `WinSCP` do have the means to calculate, from the client side, this information, but again, it is better if implemented within the protocol itself.

`SFTP` Protocol version 6, does provide the ability to get per folder size information, but it is not widely implemented.

Are there reputed `SFTP / SSH` servers and clients, with both `Windows` and `Linux` implementations, which implement `SFTP` protocol 6?

Comment: *"`SFTP` Protocol version 6, does provide the ability to get per folder size information"* – Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Looking at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00, it says -  " 'path' for which the available space should be reported.  This  'path' is not required to be the mount point path, but MAY be a directory or file contained within the mount." I have a feeling I may have misunderstood device to be a folder, rather than a filesystem or volume.OK, so SFTP v6 does not provide directory / folder size. Is there any way to get this information besides iterating through the folder? Also, conceptually, whose responsibility should it be to calculate this - server or client?

Comment: That's not anymore a question for this site.

Comment: Moreover `draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00` has nothing to do with SFTP version 6. Those extensions can be implemented by a server of any SFTP version.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I was going by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769776/sftp-check-free-space-available#19775455. The first paragraph of the answer, and a casual search led me to believe that `space-available` was specific to `SFTP 6`.

Comment: That's actually my answer. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that SFTP (any version) supports remote-side calculation of a directory size, anyway...

---

Servers supporting SFTP-6:

- Bitvise — It even implements the `space-available` extension that you refer to (which does not really need SFTP-6 and does not really do what you want) as well as OpenSSH proprietary equivalent `statvfs@openssh.com` (what is behind OpenSSH `sftp` client `df` command).
- ProFTPD – It also supports both `space-available` and `statvfs@openssh.com`.

While OpenSSH does not support SFTP-6, it (obviously) supports the `statvfs@openssh.com`.

---

Clients supporting SFTP-6:

- (my) WinSCP – It also [supports both `space-available` and `statvfs@openssh.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols#disk_usage).

Comment: Thank you for telling me about `Bitvise`. The issue with `statvfs` and indeed `space-available` extension is that they work at device, or volume level, which means, unless there's some other way, iteration through remote directory and adding file size is the only way to get remote directory size. `WinSCP` .NET library makes it easy, but I wonder why this information is not exposed by any mainstream file sharing protocol. Since the server has the storage space and it has this information, maybe expose it through the protocol. One can always `ssh` and find out, but that has own complications.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bitvise and ProFTPD, already mentioned in other replies, you may want to give Syncplify.me Server! a try, it does support SFTP v0 through v6, along with the protocol extensions to compute the size of the current VFS (with multiple VFSs per user).
Disclaimer: I am part of the development team at Syncplify.